# script to download tweets in a twitter thread? Using Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am a Twitter newbie wanting to use Tweepy to download and save Twitter threads.

For example, this latest tweet is first of a thread - https://twitter.com/BillGates/status/943131653026615296.

Wondering if there is a way to download the first tweet and the either other tweets in this thread? I have searched everywhere but cannot seem to find a way to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you look into the tweepy documentation? http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/

Comment: I did read it. Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: So I searched in Twitter developer forum. Found this link (https://twittercommunity.com/t/view-conversations-api-support/11090/46) that seems to suggest that such a feature is not readily available, but some people seem to have accomplished it. For starters, Tweetbot (a twitter app on iOS) shows tweet threads, so it must be possible...